# Would she be entitled to welfare benefits?

Tags: european-union, employment, denmark

Say an Irish national resides in another country (Denmark) and looks for work and cannot find work in her profession. But instead, she finds a part-time job that is poorly paid and she is only working 6 or 10 hours per week. A year later she seeks welfare benefits to supplement her income.

Would she be refused welfare benefits on the basis that she is not a 'worker'?

Comment: Yes. My apologies for that.

Comment: "Would she be refused" is a question of the national implementation of national and EU regulations. "Should she be refused" is a question of EU treaties. Which one are you asking? And if this is not a theoretical question, this probably requires a Danish lawyer who can be briefed on all the details of the fact.

Comment: It's 'Would she be refused?' and it's a theoretical question.

Comment: What do you mean by welfare benefits? Unemployment, child support, housing..?

Answer (score 2):

Denmark has at least [14 different categories of state benefits](https://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=1107&langId=en), each with their own particular eligibility conditions.

Taking Unemployment Benefit as an example, a claimant has to:

- have been a member of a recognised unemployment insurance fund for at least 1 year;
- have resided in Denmark (which also includes the Faroe Islands and Greenland) or in another EU/EEA country or Switzerland for 5 years within the last 12 years (requirement repealed from 1st February 2020);
- have registered at jobcentret (the Public Employment Service);
- fulfil the employment requirement;
- meet the availability requirement; if <s>your</s> [their] unemployment is self-induced there is a waiting period of 3 weeks before <s>you</s> [they] can receive unemployment benefit.

But no mention is made of not being a 'worker'